# Convert JSON data to Javascript Array in knockout

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, knockout.js

I have the following JSON Array:

```
AccessToFinancialServicesRule: {Clean: 3, Copy: 3}
BoardParticipationRule: {Clean: 3, Copy: 3}
Documents: null
EconomicDevelopmentRule: {Clean: 3, Copy: 3}
EmployeeStructureRule: {Clean: 3, Copy: 3}
EmpowermentFinanceRule: {Clean: 3, Copy: 3}
EnterpriseDevelopmentRule: {Clean: 3, Copy: 3}
OwnershipRule: {Clean: 3, Copy: 3}
PreferentialProcurementRule: {Clean: 3, Copy: 3}
ResponsibleSocialMarketingRule: {Clean: 3, Copy: 3}
SkillsDevelopmentRule: {Clean: 3, Copy: 3}
SocioEconomicDevelopmentRule: {Clean: 3, Copy: 3}
SupplierDevelopmentRule: {Clean: 3, Copy: 3}
```

and I am trying to convert it into an Array that looks like this

```
0: {label: "Ownership", clean: 3, copy: 3}
1: {label: "Skills<br>Development", clean: 3, copy: 3}
2: {label: "Localisation", clean: 3, copy: 3}
3: {label: "Socio-Economic<br>Development", clean: 3, copy: 3}
4: {label: "Board Participation", clean: 3, copy: 3}
5: {label: "Employee Structure", clean: 3, copy: 3}
6: {label: "Preferential Procurement", clean: 3, copy: 3}
7: {label: "Enterprise Development", clean: 3, copy: 3}
8: {label: "Supplier Development", clean: 3, copy: 3}
```

where each item is called `label` and shows `clean` and `copy`

I have tried the following:

```
var allItems = [data.Mappings];
            var testData = allItems.map(function(item){
                return {
                'label': item,
                'clean': item.Clean,
                'copy':item.Copy 
            };
            });

            console.log(testData)
```

but that doesnt seem to work, it makes everything into one object like this:

```
0:
clean: undefined
copy: undefined
label: {OwnershipRule: {…}, BoardParticipationRule: {…}, SkillsDevelopmentRule: {…}, EmployeeStructureRule: {…}, PreferentialProcurementRule: {…}, …}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Your data in not an array, did you mean that it's an array of objects?

Comment: @netizen yes array of object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `Object.keys` to access properties in objects here is an example:

```
const convertToArray = array.map((item) => {
  const key = Object.keys(item)

  if (item[key]) {
    return {
      label: key[0],
      clean: item[key].Clean,
      copy: item[key].Copy
    }
  }
})
```

Check link for full example: https://jsfiddle.net/qgwxbuem/

Comment: Object.keys returns an array, add [0] or .shift()

Comment: It works now, although I'd put it on the assignment to key, because the next line still checks against an array